# left-continuous process as indicator function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider the  predictable sigma-algebra on ${\mathbb R}_+\times\Omega$, denoted by $\mathcal{P}$, is generated by the left-continuous and adapted processes. Then the following holds:

The predictable sigma-algebra is generated by the sets of the form
$$ \left\{(s,t]\times A\colon t>s\ge 0, A\in\mathcal{F}_s\right\}\cup\left\{\{0\}\times A\colon A\in\mathcal{F}_0\right\}.$$
Proof:

If $B$ is any of the sets in the collection then the process ${X=1_B}$ defined by $X_t(\omega)=1_{\{(t,\omega)\in B\}}$ is adapted and left-continuous, and therefore predictable. So, $B \in\mathcal{P}$.

Can anybody explain why left- continuity holds true?

Comment: Because the indicator funtion $u\mapsto 1_{(s,t]}(u)$ is left continuous.  A picture will make this clear.

Comment: The reason is that at $t$ the indicator is still $1$?

Comment: Yes, that's it precisely.